How to add line numbers at the beginning of each verse?
I have a poem written in LaTeX. I would like to add line numbers at the beginning of each verse. So the line numbers should appear at positions 1, 6, 11, 16 etc. Here is the LaTeX text of the poem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{-20pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{poem}

\begin{stanza}
Bože mili, kud sam zašo! \verseline
\verseindent Noć me je stigla u tuđini, \verseline
\verseindent Ne znam puta, ne znam staze, \verseline
\verseindent Svuda goli kamen gaze, \verseline
\verseindent Trudne noge po pustini! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Još konaka nijesam našo! \verseline
\verseindent Sjever brije s sniježnog brda, \verseline
\verseindent A tuđincu, siromaku \verseline
\verseindent Još je veći mrak u mraku, \verseline
\verseindent Još je tvrđa zemlja tvrda! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Naokolo magla pada, \verseline
\verseindent Zastrta je mjesečina, \verseline
\verseindent Ne vidi se zvijezdam traga; \verseline
\verseindent Majko mila, majko draga, \verseline
\verseindent Da ti vidiš tvoga sina! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Da ti vidiš njega sada \verseline
\verseindent Okružena bijedom svega, \verseline
\verseindent Ti bi gorko zaplakala, \verseline
\verseindent Ruka bi ti zadrhtala \verseline
\verseindent Od žalosti - grleć njega! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Zašto tebe nijesam slušo, \verseline
\verseindent Kad si meni govorila: \verseline
\verseindent "Ne idi sinko od matere, \verseline
\verseindent Koja mekan krevet stere \verseline
\verseindent Tebi usrijed svoga krila! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ne idi, sinko, draga dušo, \verseline
\verseindent Ne idi od krova očinoga, \verseline
\verseindent Tuđa zemlja ima svoje, \verseline
\verseindent Ne spoznaje jade tvoje, \verseline
\verseindent Tuđa ljubav ljubi svoga!" - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Govoreći s sobom tako, \verseline
\verseindent K kolibici jednoj klima, \verseline
\verseindent Koju spazi iznenada, \verseline
\verseindent Umoreni putnik sada, \verseline
\verseindent I zakuca na vratima. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Otvarajuć sve polako, \verseline
\verseindent Zamišljena: Tko će biti? \verseline
\verseindent Glavu pruži jedna stara. \verseline
\verseindent "Daj u ime Božjeg dara, \verseline
\verseindent Bako, meni prenoćiti! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ne znam gdje sam - kud sam zašo, \verseline
\verseindent Noć me je stigla u tuđini, \verseline
\verseindent Ne znam puta, ne znam staze, \verseline
\verseindent Svuda goli kamen gaze, \verseline
\verseindent Trudne noge po pustini! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Drugi konak gdje bi našo! \verseline
\verseindent Sjever brije s sniježnog brda, \verseline
\verseindent A tuđincu, siromaku \verseline
\verseindent Još je veći mrak u mraku, \verseline
\verseindent Još je tvrđa zemlja tvrda. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Naokolo magla pada \verseline
\verseindent Zastrta je mjesečina, \verseline
\verseindent Ne vidi se zvijezdam traga, \verseline
\verseindent Majko mila, majko draga, \verseline
\verseindent Primi pod krov tuđeg sina!" - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
"Primila bih tebe rada; \verseline
\verseindent Ali vidiš da spavaju \verseline
\verseindent Ovdje sinka tri i ćerce, \verseline
\verseindent Koji cijelo majke s[e]rce \verseline
\verseindent I svu kuću ispunjaju!" - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
"Nij' daleko već do dana, \verseline
\verseindent Već pozdravlja pijevac vile, \verseline
\verseindent Dok zagrije danak Boži, \verseline
\verseindent Malo vatre bar naloži, \verseline
\verseindent Da otopim smrzle žile!" - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
"Vatra mi je zapretana, \verseline
\verseindent Drva ne imam skoro ništa, \verseline
\verseindent Ovo malo, što je unutra, \verseline
\verseindent Trjeba mojoj djeci sutra \verseline
\verseindent Kad se skupe kod ognjišta!" - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
"Za tuđinca ništa ne imaš \verseline
\verseindent Tuđa majko, kad te moli! \verseline
\verseindent Tuđe dijete tvoje nije!" - \verseline
\verseindent S tim mu grozne suze dvije \verseline
\verseindent Niza lica kapnu doli. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
"Gdje su ruke tvoje majke \verseline
\verseindent Sad da skupe suze sina? \verseline
\verseindent Gdje koljeno, da počine, \verseline
\verseindent Da si teško brjeme skine? \verseline
\verseindent Gdje je tvoja domovina?!" -
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ko da su mu zmije ljute \verseline
\verseindent S ovim riječ'ma srce stisle, \verseline
\verseindent Ukočeni putnik stoji, \verseline
\verseindent Leden znoj mu čelo znoji \verseline
\verseindent I otimlje mozgu misle. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ali oči uzdignute \verseline
\verseindent K strani glede - ah onamo! \verseline
\verseindent Gdje od drage domovine \verseline
\verseindent Svako jutro sunce sine, \verseline
\verseindent Tam' ga želja nosi - tamo: 
\end{stanza}
 
\begin{stanza}
"Tebi opet duša diše, \verseline
\verseindent Tebi srce opet bije, \verseline
\verseindent Domovino, majko srjeće! \verseline
\verseindent K tebi opet sin se kreće, \verseline
\verseindent Od radosti suze lije. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Primi opet svoje dijete, \verseline
\verseindent Primi vijek će tvoje biti, \verseline
\verseindent Ljubit tebe svako doba, \verseline
\verseindent U tvom polju daj mu groba, \verseline
\verseindent S tvojim cvijećem grob mu kiti!!" \looseness = -1
\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


\verselinenumberstoright
\setverselinemodulo{5}     Is this what you want?

Try placing this in your preamble:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\incrementverselinenumber}{%
  \nolinebreak\addtocounter{verselinenumber}{1}%
  \ifnum\theprintlineindex=5%
  \putverselinenumber\nobreak%
  \setcounter{printlineindex}{0}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{printlineindex}{1}%
}
\makeatother

The code shown above alters the behavior of poemscol. (It won't work for a similar package and is not particularly beautiful, but it works.) This will produce the following output:

P.S.: If you'd like to remove the page number shown in the upper right corner, write rhead{} after \usepackage{fancyhdr}.

Change how the package decides when line numbers should be printed.
The normal working is that the number is printed as soon as a counter exceeds the stated interval (default 10) minus one. Here I tell TeX to print the number when the remainder modulo the stated interval is 1.
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,ifthen}% required by poemscol
\usepackage{poemscol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[marginpar=8pt,marginparsep=-12pt]{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.1cm}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{lineindexrepeat}{5}
\renewcommand{\incrementverselinenumber}{%
\nolinebreak\addtocounter{verselinenumber}{1}%
 \@ifundefined{marksthe}{\relax}{\marksthe{verselinemark}{\theverselinenumber}}%
  \addtocounter{printlineindex}{1}%
  \ifnum\printlineindexmodulo=1
    \ifverselinenumbers\nobreak%
      \putverselinenumber\nobreak%
    \fi\nobreak%
    \setcounter{printlineindex}{0}%
   \fi%
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printlineindexmodulo}{}
 {
  \int_mod:nn { \value{verselinenumber} } { \value{lineindexrepeat} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{poem}

\begin{stanza}
Bože mili, kud sam zašo! \verseline
\verseindent Noć me je stigla u tuđini, \verseline
\verseindent Ne znam puta, ne znam staze, \verseline
\verseindent Svuda goli kamen gaze, \verseline
\verseindent Trudne noge po pustini! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Još konaka nijesam našo! \verseline
\verseindent Sjever brije s sniježnog brda, \verseline
\verseindent A tuđincu, siromaku \verseline
\verseindent Još je veći mrak u mraku, \verseline
\verseindent Još je tvrđa zemlja tvrda! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Naokolo magla pada, \verseline
\verseindent Zastrta je mjesečina, \verseline
\verseindent Ne vidi se zvijezdam traga; \verseline
\verseindent Majko mila, majko draga, \verseline
\verseindent Da ti vidiš tvoga sina! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Da ti vidiš njega sada \verseline
\verseindent Okružena bijedom svega, \verseline
\verseindent Ti bi gorko zaplakala, \verseline
\verseindent Ruka bi ti zadrhtala \verseline
\verseindent Od žalosti - grleć njega! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Zašto tebe nijesam slušo, \verseline
\verseindent Kad si meni govorila: \verseline
\verseindent ``Ne idi sinko od matere, \verseline
\verseindent Koja mekan krevet stere \verseline
\verseindent Tebi usrijed svoga krila! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ne idi, sinko, draga dušo, \verseline
\verseindent Ne idi od krova očinoga, \verseline
\verseindent Tuđa zemlja ima svoje, \verseline
\verseindent Ne spoznaje jade tvoje, \verseline
\verseindent Tuđa ljubav ljubi svoga!'' - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Govoreći s sobom tako, \verseline
\verseindent K kolibici jednoj klima, \verseline
\verseindent Koju spazi iznenada, \verseline
\verseindent Umoreni putnik sada, \verseline
\verseindent I zakuca na vratima. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Otvarajuć sve polako, \verseline
\verseindent Zamišljena: Tko će biti? \verseline
\verseindent Glavu pruži jedna stara. \verseline
\verseindent ``Daj u ime Božjeg dara, \verseline
\verseindent Bako, meni prenoćiti! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ne znam gdje sam - kud sam zašo, \verseline
\verseindent Noć me je stigla u tuđini, \verseline
\verseindent Ne znam puta, ne znam staze, \verseline
\verseindent Svuda goli kamen gaze, \verseline
\verseindent Trudne noge po pustini! 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Drugi konak gdje bi našo! \verseline
\verseindent Sjever brije s sniježnog brda, \verseline
\verseindent A tuđincu, siromaku \verseline
\verseindent Još je veći mrak u mraku, \verseline
\verseindent Još je tvrđa zemlja tvrda. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Naokolo magla pada \verseline
\verseindent Zastrta je mjesečina, \verseline
\verseindent Ne vidi se zvijezdam traga, \verseline
\verseindent Majko mila, majko draga, \verseline
\verseindent Primi pod krov tuđeg sina!'' - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
``Primila bih tebe rada; \verseline
\verseindent Ali vidiš da spavaju \verseline
\verseindent Ovdje sinka tri i ćerce, \verseline
\verseindent Koji cijelo majke s[e]rce \verseline
\verseindent I svu kuću ispunjaju!'' - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
``Nij' daleko već do dana, \verseline
\verseindent Već pozdravlja pijevac vile, \verseline
\verseindent Dok zagrije danak Boži, \verseline
\verseindent Malo vatre bar naloži, \verseline
\verseindent Da otopim smrzle žile!'' - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
``Vatra mi je zapretana, \verseline
\verseindent Drva ne imam skoro ništa, \verseline
\verseindent Ovo malo, što je unutra, \verseline
\verseindent Trjeba mojoj djeci sutra \verseline
\verseindent Kad se skupe kod ognjišta!'' - 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
``Za tuđinca ništa ne imaš \verseline
\verseindent Tuđa majko, kad te moli! \verseline
\verseindent Tuđe dijete tvoje nije!'' - \verseline
\verseindent S tim mu grozne suze dvije \verseline
\verseindent Niza lica kapnu doli. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
``Gdje su ruke tvoje majke \verseline
\verseindent Sad da skupe suze sina? \verseline
\verseindent Gdje koljeno, da počine, \verseline
\verseindent Da si teško brjeme skine? \verseline
\verseindent Gdje je tvoja domovina?!'' -
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ko da su mu zmije ljute \verseline
\verseindent S ovim riječ'ma srce stisle, \verseline
\verseindent Ukočeni putnik stoji, \verseline
\verseindent Leden znoj mu čelo znoji \verseline
\verseindent I otimlje mozgu misle. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Ali oči uzdignute \verseline
\verseindent K strani glede - ah onamo! \verseline
\verseindent Gdje od drage domovine \verseline
\verseindent Svako jutro sunce sine, \verseline
\verseindent Tam' ga želja nosi - tamo: 
\end{stanza}
 
\begin{stanza}
``Tebi opet duša diše, \verseline
\verseindent Tebi srce opet bije, \verseline
\verseindent Domovino, majko srjeće! \verseline
\verseindent K tebi opet sin se kreće, \verseline
\verseindent Od radosti suze lije. 
\end{stanza}

\begin{stanza}
Primi opet svoje dijete, \verseline
\verseindent Primi vijek će tvoje biti, \verseline
\verseindent Ljubit tebe svako doba, \verseline
\verseindent U tvom polju daj mu groba, \verseline
\verseindent S tvojim cvijećem grob mu kiti!!'' \looseness = -1
\end{stanza}
\end{poem}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}

I made a few fixes to the settings of \marginparwidth and \marginparsep to avoid very annoying warnings and also used twoside to avoid even more annoying warnings.
Why does the package requires geometry, fancyhdrandifthen` without loading them? A mystery.
I also changed all " into correct quotes.

